# Add favorite movie to Favorite Page from a json list of movies?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a listview where I show some movies which I get from a json file. I have added a button "Add favorite" so the movies that I select should be displayed on another page "Favorites Page". When I unselect that button, the movie should be removed from the "Favorites Page". I want this data to be saved even after I restart my app. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: You can make a local storage database (sqflite) and store favorites movies there.

Comment: @AbdelbakiBoukerche I store them in Firestore and it works. I made a button that changes its Icon when it is clicked. For example if the movie its not in Favorites Page, the icon is "+", when I click it should change to "✓". The problem is that when I click one movie, it changes the icon of all movies in the list. And when I reload the page, the icon is back at its initial form, so "+", even for movies that are in Favorites page.

Comment: Oh i see. you can add a field for a user document that contains a List of ID's of favorite movies. and if you a user marks a movie as favorite add the movie to that List. and when your building the listView for all movies check if movie id is in the favorites List and build your UI according.

Comment: @AbdelbakiBoukerche Yes this is the logic that I was trying to follow. I wanted to check if the movie title exists in the collection where the favorite movies are stored, if yes then the icon should be '✓' and user should not be able to add it again, if no then the icon should be '+' and the user will be able to add it to the favorite list. But I am having difficulties to implement it.

Comment: Just use "ternary operator" and show the Icon accordingly.

Comment: I managed to check if it exists or not, and return the Icon properly, but the problem is that if one movie exists in the favorite list page, all movies in my movie list have the icon  '✓' . I think its because of the ListView, since I iterate like this inside the ListView, if movies[index].title exists, return Icon '✓' else '+'. Dont know how to make it only for the specific movie selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211103/discussion-between-peakystewie-and-abdelbaki-boukerche).